# can my internet provider see my communications?

Tags: privacy, wifi, internet

Can my ISP see what i am communicating through Skype, Facebook, Yahoo-Mail and so on?

I am not asking this from a legal perspective, but only from a technical one.
Also I am not talking about keyloggers, spywares and similar stuff.

I read similar questions but accepted answers are contradictory to each others so I have no idea which one is right.

Comment: When you say that you found various answers but they contradict each other, then please post links and point out where you see contradictions. Otherwise you will just get another contradicting answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no they cannot, but yes they can.

You have to accept that there is a yes and no to this question, SSL should protect your communication from snooping even from an ISP but if an ISP wanted to do something similar to a MitM they could do so with a fair amount of ease but I will put this down to "similar stuff"....

To reexplain SSL The client and the webserver exchange certificates which are normally signed by a 3rd party to validate that the webserver you are connected to is the genuine one. This SSL checking is to ensure you are connected to the real server and not an attacker, this rule applies to a MitM attack even if done by an ISP you would have to be over an insecure (http, port 80 etc) connection for them to be able to read it. The rules that apply to the rest of the world apply to an ISP they have no special power really, just maybe more resource and a better tactical point in the network infrastructure. so if you are on https your traffic is encrypted and cannot be read.

Comment: @karmoudkarmoud yes, all about the ssl, this will stop or allow them to read it, if it goes through their network they can save the data even the encrypted bytes can be saved, doesn't mean they can read them though.

Comment: @karmoudkarmoud one more thing to mention, they can see the sites you visit the sites have to resolve they can see anything you are visiting with ease, just not what you are typing into the site.